# Finding first & last numbers

Tags: numbers

Sorry, new to this so hopefully I can explain it well enough

Using below example of text I need regex to find the line number after the FREE TEXT-ID line.

I then need to find the final line number of ANY of the lines.

This will need to be two separate regex codes as I need use each result in different places.

So using this example regex needs to locate 3 & 33.

HELP please!  Many thanks

```
DOCI-AC ACCT-7XV.1C54071
  2. FREE TEXT-ID/381920/61668/C54071-MITCHELL/DANIELMR
  **3**. AGT INF-A5
  4. FREE TEXT-RC/*1/01
  5. FREE TEXT-BA/*1/A5
  6. FREE TEXT-TA/*1/A5
  7. FREE TEXT-FF6/*1/1
  8. FREE TEXT-FF63/*1/0
  9. FREE TEXT-FF9/*1/10-AUG-2020
 10. FREE TEXT-FF12/*1/DANIEL MITCHELL
 11. FREE TEXT-FF60/*1/3
 12. FREE TEXT-FF61/*1/0
 13. FREE TEXT-EC/*1/101
 14. FREE TEXT-RF/*1/350.00
 15. FREE TEXT-LF/*1/318.00
 16. FREE TEXT-FF95/*1/LOWEST FARE ACCEPTED
 17. FREE TEXT-SF/*1/340.00
 18. FREE TEXT-MS/*1/PC39/V1TFEE/CP100/A20.00
 19. FREE TEXT-RC/*2/03
 20. FREE TEXT-BA/*2/A5
 21. FREE TEXT-TA/*2/A5
 22. FREE TEXT-FF6/*2/2
 23. FREE TEXT-FF63/*2/0
 24. FREE TEXT-FF9/*2/10-AUG-2020
 25. FREE TEXT-FF12/*2/DANIEL MITCHELL
 26. FREE TEXT-FF60/*2/3
 27. FREE TEXT-FF61/*2/0
 28. FREE TEXT-EC/*2/140*
 29. FREE TEXT-RF/*2/1500.00
 30. FREE TEXT-LF/*2/950.00
 31. FREE TEXT-FF95/*2/LOWEST FARE ACCEPTED
 32. FREE TEXT-SF/*2/950.00
 **33**. FREE TEXT-MS/*2/PC39/V1TFEE/CP100/A40.00
>
```